# Where can someone view the source code for the new Trinity wallet?

Tags: wallet, android-wallet

The Trinity Wallet (aka UCL IOTA Wallet) is to be released very shortly.

Where can someone view the source code to the Trinity wallet?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a resource request which SE is not terribly good at.

Answer (score 4):

Trinity wallet’s source code can be accessed here: https://github.com/iotaledger/trinity-wallet